# change css inline using jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have a button like this

```
<input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit Selected" class="emrBTN" style="top:5;right:95;width:100; visibility:hidden" />
```

I want to change the visibility to visible using jquery onclick ob a button event. How can I do that.
Thanks

Comment: Your CSS is invalid, lengths require a unit unless they are 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
jQuery('#btnEdit').css('visibility', 'visible');
```

It is very near the top of the CSS section of the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: Can we do this :

$('.emrBTN').css('visibility', 'visible');

And how to change multiple css attributes say css('visibility', 'visible') and css('position', 'relative') simultaneously ??

Answer (score 2):

Solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/hY3eg/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Make Visible" id="makeVisible"/>

<input type="button" id="btnEdit" value="Edit Selected" class="emrBTN" style="top:5;right:95;width:100; visibility:hidden" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#makeVisible").click(function() {
        $("#btnEdit").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
});
```